# ADF - copy csv from source to target if its with in 2 days and achieve the older target version

Tags: azure-data-factory

My issue: File is not checking if its older than 2 days or not. Regardless its copying the file and True part is getting executed which is achieving the file.
How do i check execute True condition if only file is less than 2 days old

[image: Get Metadata]

[image: Metdadata]

[image: If condition]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are getting this behavior because **modifiedDatetimeStart** and **modifiedDatetimeEnd** properties does not work to get metadata from a file and it is meant for getting metadata from a folder.  This will result in all the files modified within the mentioned range.  Please refer to the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/control-flow-get-metadata-activity) for details.

**Example:**

**Storage**
[image]

**ADF (Get Metadata)**
[image]

**Result:**

[image]

You can change your approach and get the last modified date of the file using **Get Metadata** and compare it against your defined range using expression like below -
`@if(greaterOrEquals(ticks(activity('Get Metadata_File').output.lastModified),ticks(adddays(utcnow(),-2))),True,False)`.

Please check the below Gif for reference -
[image]

Comment: Hi Saurabh, Thanks a lot, it works great. Can you please explain me the second part ticks(adddays(utcnow(),-2))),True,False). I wanted to compare target file date to today, if there is any new file between Target date to Today that then copy it achieve. what should be changed in this @if(greaterOrEquals(ticks(activity('Get Metadata_File').output.lastModified),ticks(adddays(utcnow(),-0))),True,False). is this correct?

Comment: @if(lessOrEquals(ticks(activity('Get Metadata_File').output.lastModified),ticks(adddays(utcnow(),0))),True,False)